# How to navigate to intra page link by button click on vuejs form

Tags: vue.js, hyperlink, vuejs2, routerlink

I have a  intralink on a page:

```
<h3 id="report">Preview Report</h3>
```

and when I submit form I call the method as shown below

```
methods: {
        generateReport: function(link) {
            console.log(link);
            window.location.href = "report"
        }

    }
```

instead of scrolling down below to to where intra page link `report` is it navigates to a different page (default homepage)

Comment: What do you mean by intra page link ,a link element on the same page  ? 
if you want to just scroll to an element in the page use scrollIntoView or if you want to have a hased url link to the element so that on refresh the scroll position is maintained you can change the url hash and <a href="#section-two">Section Two</a> and have a hash for the element ID

Answer (score 0):

```
<h3 id="report" ref="report-link">Preview Report</h3>


methods: {
        generateReport: function(link) {
            console.log(link);
            $ref['report-link'].scrollIntoView()
             //or if you are receiving the link element dom itself as the param //just use
            link.scrollIntoView()


        }

    }
```

Comment: if I use `$ref['report-link'].scrollIntoView()` then I get error `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $ref` if I use the `link.scrollIntoView()` then I get error: TypeError: link.scrollIntoView is not a function. (In 'link.scrollIntoView()', 'link.scrollIntoView' is undefined)

Comment: $refs['ref-name'] sorry typo , try this

Comment: `this.$refs['report-link']`